# Resolution and long exact sheaf sequence of cohomology groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

(I am reading Huybrechts's Complex Geometry)

I also looked some classic sources, but I didn't find anything addressing the below.

---

**Proposition $B.0.35$**

Let $$0\longrightarrow  \mathcal{F}^0\longrightarrow \mathcal{F}^1\longrightarrow \mathcal{F}^2\longrightarrow  0$$
be a short exact sequence of sheaves on M. Then there exists a long exact
cohomology sequence $$ 0\to H^0(M,\mathcal{F}^0)\to H^0(M,\mathcal{F}^1)\to H^0(M,\mathcal{F}^2)\to\ldots  H^2(M,\mathcal{F}^2)\to\ldots $$

So now I think there is some abuse of notation here, so let me write what I think is happening. For every sheaf $\mathcal{F}^0,\mathcal{F}^1,\mathcal{F}^2$ there exist a resolution on the global sections i.e. For $  \mathcal{F}^{0}$ we have the long  sequence

$$0\longrightarrow \mathcal{F}^{0}(M) \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}^{0}(M)^0\longrightarrow  \mathcal{F}^{0}(M)^1\longrightarrow  \mathcal{F}^{0}(M)^2\longrightarrow \ldots$$

And similarly with $  \mathcal{F}^{1},  \mathcal{F}^{2}$

And when we write $H^1(M,\mathcal{F}^0)$ we actually mean $\dfrac{ \operatorname{Ker}(\phi^1 :\mathcal{F}^{0}(M)^1 \to \mathcal{F}^{0}(M)^2}{\operatorname{Im}(\phi^0 : \mathcal{F}^{0}(M)^0\to \mathcal{F}^{0}(M)^1}$

***My question is***: **how we map these elements in the long exact sequence ?**

The obvious way (let's say for the above example) to map $H^1(M,\mathcal{F}^0)\longrightarrow H^1(M,\mathcal{F}^1) $ would be to map $[a]\in H^1(M,\mathcal{F}^0)$ via the map $\psi: \mathcal{F}^0\longrightarrow \mathcal{F}^1$ somehow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean $\mathcal{F}^0(M)^1$? However your question is answered by general derived functor theory, the snake lemma; this is just some mysterious connecting homomorphism which can be made explicit if you fix suitable specific resolutions of the $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ (via the Horseshoe lemma!) but this is rarely desirable

Comment: @FShrike what I mean is that $F^0$, let's call it $A$ instead, is a sheaf on $M$ so there is a long exact sequence of $A$ on the global sections where the cohomology is defined, i.e. $0\to A^0(M)\to A^1(M)\to A^2(M)\ldots$

Comment: @FShrike  Am I wrong here ? Did I confuse something?  How else $H^5(M,F^0)$ makes senses ?

Comment: @FShrike sorry the sequence should be like that $0\to A(M)\to A^0(M)\to A^1(M)\to A^2(M)\ldots$

Comment: @FShrike Also do you have an easy example, for a specific resolution, where you apply the snake lemma to obtain explicit these maps?

Comment: If I wrote an answer it would more or less be an exact copy of what could be found in, say, Weibel's very readable treatment of the basic construction of the derived functor and proof that it is a (co)homological $\delta$-functor. For sheaf cohomology in particular I'm told that we usually don't think about the specific cohomology classes (unlike with, say, singular cohomology, where the cohomology classes are clearly represented by something we can geometrically understand) so thinking about the maps of the long exact sequence at the set theoretic, elementwise level is unhelpful.

Comment: What is very helpful is the general machinery that tells you properties e.g. naturality of this LES and exactness and independence of the choice of $\Gamma$-acyclic resolution of the sheaves. It is far more important that all maps in question exist, but in total generality writing an explicit formula for them would be awful

Comment: Please note that the long sequence on global sections in not exact. Otherwise you would have $H^i(M, \mathcal F^0) = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @red_trumpet the long sequence of cohomology is exact; the resolution $0\to A(M)\to\ldots $ is not exact. I don't see the point thought what do you want to say ?

Comment: In your post you write "For $\mathcal F^0$ we have the long exact sequence $$0 \to \mathcal F^0(M) \to \mathcal F^0(M)^0 \to \mathcal F^0(M)^1 \to \dotsc"$$ That is a sequence on global sections, which is not exact.

Comment: @red_trumpet, I see it's a mistake, I meant to say just long.